# pcl_ros / tf : how to use latest transform instead of waiting?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When calling "pcl_ros::transformPointCloud" I get the error:

```
[ERROR] [1480244411.676958769, 1224.030000000]: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1224.022000000 but the latest data is at time 1224.021000000, when looking up transform from frame [base_laser_link] to frame [odom]
```

I know this could be solved by calling "waitForTransform", but in this specific case speed is more important than precision.
So I would like to use the latest available transform, even if a little off, rather than wait for the more suitable one.
I.e. in the example above it would use the tf at 1225.021.

Any way to do this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248887/pcl_ros-/-tf-:-how-to-use-latest-transform-instead-of-waiting-?/) by [vincent78](https://answers.ros.org/users/23250/vincent78/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-27**:
May I suggest a title fix? Your question is really about how to transform a `PointCloud` using the latest transform available. That uses TF, but is specific to `pcl_ros`. Would be good to mention that in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `ros::Time(0)` instead of the actual timestamp. In `pcl_ros`, that is probably possible with the [pcl_ros::transformPointCloud(.., const ros::Time &target_time, ..)](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html#a34090d5c8739e1a31749ccf0fd807f91) overload.

See also the [Learning about tf and time (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20(C%2B%2B)) tutorial and the TF docs for `lookupTransform()` ([here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1BufferInterface.html#a7b32d6bdc0ae5f2cdba867dc50e50939) in `tf2_ros::BufferInterface` fi).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-11-27**:
This is the answer to your question. However I would suggest that you review your assumption that waiting the approximately 1 millisecond for the correct data to come in is worse than using incorrect data. And to do approximation correctly there are a lot more corner cases that need to be handled.